# Unable to re assign local variables

Tags: kotlin

```
fun test(temp: Int) {
    temp = 5
}
```

The compiler throws an error saying "val cannot be reassigned".

Are local variables read only in Kotlin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function parameters are always read-only (i.e. declared as `val`);
If you want to change it, you will need to use a (new) local variable:

```
fun test(temp: Int) {
   var myTemp = temp
   myTemp = 5
}
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. Why are function params read only? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Kotlin favors immutability over mutability, this is reflected in parameters being read-only by default. If you want to reassign it, you can shadow it by using a variable with the same name: `var temp = temp`

Comment: Assigning value to a parameter is a bad practice in Java. One might think that it would change value of object outside of the function. It Kotlin it is forbidden and it was a good decision imo.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is not a local variable - it is a function parameter. There is no point of reassigning it.